# Issue when download html files from asp.net mvc project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

When I tried to download arabic files from mvc project, I found the arabic data is changed to special characters like this `ØªØ§Ø±ÙŠØ® Ø§Ù„Ø´ÙƒÙˆÙ‰`

That's my code that I use in download:

```
System.Web.Mvc.FileStreamResult FSR = new FileStreamResult(stream, "application/msword");
FSR.FileDownloadName = CorrespondenceselectedFile.FileName;
return FSR;
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems like the text "تاريخ الشكوى" ("Date of the complaint") is decoded with the default encoding instead of UTF-8.

You should probably correct the encoding somewhere in your code (not part of the shown code) or do it manually (not preferred):

```
string ascii = "ØªØ§Ø±ÙŠØ® Ø§Ù„Ø´ÙƒÙˆÙ‰";
var bytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(ascii);
string utf8 = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
// utf = تاريخ الشكوى
```